# XSL remove empty child nodes but if no child create one

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to format the following XML removing all "parameters" nodes that are empty (without a "key" child node) but if all are empty I need to create one.
Let say I need to have at least one "parameters" node for each "coverage"

Input XML:

```
<root>
   <coverages>
      <parameters> 
        <enumValues/>
      </parameters>
      <parameters>
        <enumValues/>
      </parameters>
      <parameters>
        <enumValues/>
      </parameters>
      <id>P01</id>
      <name>P01 coverage</name>
      <parameters>
        <key>key1</key>
        <name>Key1 Name</name>
        <defaultValue>1</defaultValue>
      </parameters>
   </coverages>
   <coverages>
      <parameters>
        <enumValues/>
      </parameters>
      <parameters>
        <enumValues/>
      </parameters>
      <parameters>
        <enumValues/>
      </parameters>
      <id>P03</id>
      <name>P03 coverage</name>
   </coverages>
</root>
```

The expected output is:

```
<root>
    <coverages>
        <id>P01</id>
        <name>P01 coverage</name>
        <parameters>
            <key>key1</key>
            <name>Key1 Name</name>
            <defaultValue>1</defaultValue>
        </parameters>
    </coverages>
    <coverages>
        <id>P03</id>
        <name>P03 coverage</name>
        <parameters>
            <key>key2</key>
            <name>Key2 Name</name>
            <defaultValue>2</defaultValue>
        </parameters>
    </coverages>
</root>
```

I'm actually stuck with the transform to apply, because I can easily remove the empty nodes, but then I don't have a clue how to add one

I'm using the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="coverages/parameters[not(descendant::key[not(*)][normalize-space()])]" />
```

but this just removes the empty ones

Comment: Where would the values for the created `parameters` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="parameters[not(key)]"/>

<xsl:template match="coverages[not(parameters/key)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <parameters>
            <key>some value</key>
            <name>some value</name>
            <defaultValue>some value</defaultValue>
        </parameters>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip Michael,actually the solution was simpler than I thought, the apply-templates before adding the "fake" node. I was playing with that but eventually setting it in the wrong position.